# C++ Segmentation Fault on For Loop

Tags: c++, loops, segmentation-fault

Everything works fine right up until the last value of index 19. In fact, all values are printed and what not. Once it prints the final value & index, it seg faults. I am assuming this is because it is trying to access the 20th value. How would I prevent this from occurring?

MAIN FILE CODE:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < list.length())
{
  cout << list.getNextItem(index) << " " << index << "\n";
  index++;
}
```

HEADER CODE:

```
template <class Type>
Type doublyLinkedList<Type>::getNextItem(const Type& val) const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list

    current = first;  //set current to point to the first node

    for (index=0; index < val; index++)
    {
        if (current != NULL)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return current->info;
}//end getNextItem
```

Comment: That's a very weird implementation. In `getNextItem` Where is `index` initialized? Why is the list traversed like a poor man's vector?

Comment: Also, where did the magic numbers 19 and 20 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `current->info` is outside null checking. When `current` is null, you can't access its pointer and cause seg fault

Comment: What other specific code should I include here? The header file is about 7 printed pages which is why I didn't post that all. 

The only thing I changed so far was at the bottom of this function:
       
    **if(current == NULL)
    return 0;
    else
    return current->info;**
    


Also, I tried keeping it as val-1, so that it didn't ever get to point at NULL, but that just left it missing one element in the list (last one).

Comment: Using -1 still not safe (It reference to invalid address). It depends on what you are expecting to return (your logic) to tell the consumer when there is no more Item to be returned.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (index=0; index < val; index++)
{
    if (current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
}
return current->info;
```

You assign `current` to `current->next`. When it's `null` *then* you to try to return `current->info` when `current` is  ... null.

At least that's my suspicion; the code you post is incomplete and it's impossible to give you a concrete answer ... but that certainly looks like a culprit.